# How to fix leading in cals table (cals.sty)

Tags: tables, cals

% Leading problem between Row 2, Row3 and Row4 in case of super and subscript value

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{cals}



\begin{document}

\par\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}}
\thead{\bfseries\brow \cell{col1} \cell{col2} \cell{col3} \cell{col4}\erow\mdseries}
\brow \cell{col1}\cell{r1,col2} \cell{r1,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1} \cell{r2,col2} \cell{r2,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1$_3^3$} \cell{r3,col2$^1_5$} \cell{r3,col3}\cell{col4} \erow
\brow \cell{col1} \cell{r4,col2} \cell{r4,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1$5^+_5$} \cell{r5,col2} \cell{r5,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
 \end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote the `cals` user guide:

> To vertically align a cell to the middle or bottom, add `\vfil` or
>   `\vfill` before the cell content.

The following shows the use of the different alignment options when combined with a table cell that contains super- and subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}}
\brow \cell{col1$_3^3$} \cell{top} \cell{\vfil center}\cell{\vfill bottom} \erow
\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to vertically center the text in rows that contain super- and subscripts, you can use `\vfil` as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}}
\thead{\bfseries\brow \cell{col1} \cell{col2} \cell{col3} \cell{col4}\erow\mdseries}
\brow \cell{col1}\cell{r1,col2} \cell{r1,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1} \cell{r2,col2} \cell{r2,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1$_3^3$} \cell{r3,col2$^1_5$} \cell{\vfil r3,col3}\cell{\vfil col4} \erow
\brow \cell{col1} \cell{r4,col2} \cell{r4,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1$5^+_5$} \cell{\vfil r5,col2} \cell{\vfil r5,col3} \cell{\vfil col4}\erow
 \end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the superscript is too high for the alignment. The cals package hopes that the height of the first line is not larger than of the letters "Ml". The possible solutions are:

1) Automatic baseline alignment:

```
\cell{
 \vskip-\baselineskip \phantom{ly}\par
 col1$_3^3$
}
```

2) Bigger height for all first lines:

```
\cell{\strut r5,col2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The \strut command worked but there is still little variation in leading  due to \cell{\strut col1$_f^1$}. Please suggest how can rid this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to equalize the rows, you can increase the leading:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}\linespread{1.25}\selectfont
\colwidths{{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}{50pt}}
\thead{\bfseries\brow \cell{col1} \cell{col2} \cell{col3} \cell{col4}\erow\mdseries}
\brow \cell{col1}\cell{r1,col2} \cell{r1,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1} \cell{r2,col2} \cell{r2,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1$_3^3$} \cell{r3,col2$^1_5$} \cell{r3,col3}\cell{col4} \erow
\brow \cell{col1} \cell{r4,col2} \cell{r4,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\brow \cell{col1$5^+_5$} \cell{r5,col2} \cell{r5,col3} \cell{col4}\erow
\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The value 1.25 is just by way of example; with 1.1 we'd get

[image]